# Excel PivotTables: How to have a hierarchical collapsible list with varying levels

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image]

When I try to create the above using a PivotTable, I get the blank cells as expandable levels as well. So for example Item A has 2 blank sub-levels and Item E has 3, when they should have none.

Comment: what have you tried ? I would recommend googling how to insert a pivot table as a first option (this should always be a first option btw)

Comment: Your data orientation is wrong that's why you are struggling to get products is desire order,,, do this create one column for Bag Category,,, Like Large, Medium & Small and in next column put their respective sub category next you may keep column for their values,, and make Pivot Table !!

Comment: @RajeshS Not really, if I do what you said I will just get blank values different levels. They will still be there. The data orientation is correct, it is organised in exactly the levels of hierarchy.

Comment: @BradenCutajar ,, check the post ,, I'm sure this helps you,,, considering data set supplied by you,, I've tried the best possible,, even VBA macro do the same,, this is unusual data set to create PT,,, so you are getting +10 ☺

Comment: You can Transform it to an Table to add a header and use the table to Create a PivotTable, drag all Fields to Rows.

Answer (score 0):

*This is what, is possible using the data shared by the OP:*

**:Caveat:**

*To get the correct order I've modified the data orientation.*

- *Readers think twice before getting judgmental to vote the post, since
  data shared by OP is unusual and Text, otherwise BLANK should be
  replaced by ZERO.*
- *Please post a better solution if you can.*

---

---

**Before Remove BLANKS:**

[image]

---

**After Remove BLANKS:**

[image]

**How remove BLANKS:**

- Select BLANK cells in PT one by one while holding **Ctrl key**.
- **R**ight Click then **F**ormat cells.
- From **C**ustom replace **G**ENERAL with `;;;`.

---

**N.B.**

- You may replace BLANK with any meaning full text.
- Remove BLANKS from FILTER, spoils the results.